# how to convert char ** to unique_ptr array?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

The old code is as below:

```
    char** wargv = new char*[argc];//memory leak!
    for(int k = 0; k < argc; ++k)
    {
        wargv[k] = new char[strlen(argv[k]) + 1];
        strncpy(wargv[k], argv[k], strlen(argv[k]));
        wargv[k][strlen(argv[k])] = '\0';
    }
```

because there may cause memory leak, so I want to convert `wargv` to `unique_ptr`. How to make it?
I know how to convert `char*` to `unique_ptr`, the code below works:

```
int size_t = 10;
std::unique_ptr<char[]> wargv(new char[size_t]{0});
strncpy(wargv.get(), "abcdef", size_t);
```

but I don't know how to convert `char **` to `unique_ptr`, I tried vector,but it doesn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `std::vector<std::string>` instead?

Comment: See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135178/c-array-of-char-using-unique-ptr - `using array_ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<char[]>;
using array_of_arrays_type = std::unique_ptr<array_ptr_type[]>;`

Comment: I don't want to release the memory manually，the `wargv` will pass in another function.

Comment: You should not use `size_t` as a variable name. It is a standard type name. Besides, I recommend considering the suggestion of @Someprogrammerdude.

Comment: Using smart pointers for both "dimensions" will not solve the problem if you want to pass the result to a function expecting a `char*` arguments. Use standard C++ containers and strings as long as you can, then explicitly convert to the expected only when really needed. Use the (temporary) `char**` variable. Then explicitly free everything.

Comment: ok, thx all above

Answer (score 0):

As @Some programmer dude commented, `std::vector<std::string>` should be a better choice than `std::unique_ptr<>`, with memory allocation management.

I try to write a simple example and it works well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::vector<std::string> collection(argc);
  for (auto i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    collection[i] = argv[i];
  }

  for (const auto& arg : collection) {
    std::cout << arg << "\n";
  }
}
```